# WPF Triggering a binding based on ListBoxItem Template

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, triggers

The title may be a little offtopic, so i will try to expain it with every detail. I have an WPF application that im working on. I set my own styles for `ListBoxItem` (`GenreStyle` && `StationStyle`) and a style for`ItemContainerStyle`.

This is how my `GenreStyle` looks like :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GenreStyle">
    <Grid Width="170" Height="170" Background="Transparent">
        <Image x:Name="GenreImage" Tag="{Binding Genre}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="{Binding GenreSource}" Width="140" Height="140"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is how my `StationStyle` looks like :

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StationStyle">
    <Grid x:Name="Gridder" Tag="{Binding SItem.StationName}" Width="125" Height="55">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectagler" Width="120" Height="50" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="#FFB20000"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="StationName" Text="{Binding SItem.StationName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="StationCountry" Text="{Binding SItem.StationCountry}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Light" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,8"/>
        <Image Tag="{Binding SItem.StationName}" Width="15" Height="15" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding FavSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is my `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
    <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter
                      x:Name="contentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.Template" Value="{StaticResource GenreStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Genre}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.Template" Value="{StaticResource StationStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Sitem.StationName}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**As you can see** in the `ItemContainerStyle` i set a `Trigger` for the `ListBoxItem.Template`.And if the `ListBoxItem.Template` is `GenreStyle` i want to bing the `Tag` property from a different value.But this fails with an exception in my main `XAML` before my application loads.

I set my `ListBox` like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="StationsListLB" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GenreStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ContainerStyle}">
```

**NOTE** -- I change my `ListBoxItem.Template` from C# code several times.

The error i get is this :

```
System.Windows.DataTemplate' is not a valid value for property 'Template'.
```

**How can i set my triggers in the `ItemContainerStyle` in order to change the binding??**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ListBoxItem.Template` valid value is `ControlTemplate` and not `DataTemplate`.

Comment: You are right, i didnt see it. But now im more confused. How can i attach this trigger to an DataTemplate?